# Objects States Not Clear After Closing Window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've following code :

```
    private void ShowOfflineIMs(bool hasOffline)
    {
        if (hasOffline)
        {
            _offlineDisplayerThread = new Thread(OpenOfflineWindow);
            _offlineDisplayerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            _offlineDisplayerThread.Start();
        }
    }

    private void OpenOfflineWindow()
    {
        var offlineWindow = new OfflineWindow();
        offlineWindow.Closed += (sender, args) => Dispatcher.ExitAllFrames();
        offlineWindow.Show();
        Dispatcher.Run();
    }
```

After I close the form objects hold their states inside the `Window`. How can I dispose `Window` after it's closed.

Thanks in Advance.